# JSON IllegalStateException (Expected Object but found String)

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have been looking at this for a while and can't seem to figure this out. I have a bit of a time sensitive deadline so if anyone has any suggestions as to why this is happening it would help!

JSON result:

```
{"py/object": "obj", "values": [63542, 56866, 47790, 62456, 49279, 43555, 45195, 59769, 58949, 59286, 54615, 48464, 53866, 56288, 55735, 45681, 62780, 61144, 49164, 60120, 55973, 49670, 58078, 49363, 48753, 52036, 47628, 57778, 60026, 56987, 60179]}
```

JAVA model:

```
public class Obj implements Serializable {

    protected static class JSON_FIELDS { 
        public static final String VALUE_LIST = "values";
    }

    @SerializedName(JSON_FIELDS.VALUE_LIST)
    public Integer[] valuesReturned;
}
```

Parsing Code:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(
        result.getBytes(Charset.defaultCharset()));
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);

Obj vals = gson.fromJson(reader, Obj.class);
```

But I am getting the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1
```

I am not sure where the string/object mixup is occurring, seems correct to me?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is with your json syntax only...Log your json and check whether its returning the json in correct format

Comment: Blind guess: the `/` in `py/object`. It should be escaped, cf http://www.json.org (section #string)

Comment: I take it `result` is a `String`? Why don't you just fetch the source directly instead of slurping it into a string?

Comment: Just log the result(json string) that causes the problem and share at your question. You are not receiving the json that you are expecting.

Comment: The result is just an EOFStream object, not the JSON.

Comment: Ok then convert that stream to string and share with us.